# Is this a reasonable Scala monad?

Tags: scala, monads

I found myself writing code of the form...

```
val foo : Foo = ???

val step1 : Foo = {
  if ( someCharacteristic( foo ) )
    someTransformation( foo )
  else
    foo
}
val step2 : Foo = {
  if ( otherCharacteristic( foo ) )
    otherTransformation( foo )
  else
    foo
}

val result = step2;
```

That seemed awkward, and it seemed like this sort of ugly stepwise processing could be monadified. I've used but not written Scala monads; I thought I'd give it a shot. What I have seems to work, but I found proving the monad laws surprisingly challenging. I'm not sure I've got a valid monad, and wonder whether there is some subtle problem that would bite me someday if I haven't. FWIW, here's the code, any comments would be very welcome.

```
package dumbmonad;

import scala.language.implicitConversions;

object If {
  implicit def unwrap[T]( ift : If[T] ) = ift.value;

  def evaluate[T]( ift : If[T] ) : T = if ( ift.condition( ift.value ) ) ift.transformation( ift.value ) else ift.value;

  def flatten[T]( outer : If[If[T]] ) : If[T] = evaluate( outer );

  def apply[T]( value : T ) : If[T] = apply( value, _ => false, identity );
}

case class If[T]( val value : T, val condition : (T)=>Boolean, val transformation : (T)=>T ) {

  lazy val evaluate : T = If.evaluate( this );

  def map[S]( f : (T) => S ) : If[S] = If( f( this.evaluate ) )
  def flatMap[S]( f : (T) => If[S] ) : If[S] = If.flatten( this.map( f ) )
}
```

I use it like this:

```
import dumbmonad._;
import dumbmonad.If._;

val foo : Foo = ???

for {
  a <- If( foo, someCharacteristic, someTransformation )
  b <- If( a, otherCharacteristic, otherTransformation )
} yield b;

val result : Foo = b; // implicit call to If.unwrap( ... )
```

Is this terrible?

Comment: Umm... I think you could easily solve the problem above with a `Map` (or even just a sequence of tuples) and two basic operations: `filter` and `foldLeft`. :) Although it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the ternary operator (x ? y : z) instead, but I just realized it does not exist in Scala.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947535) is link about this topic.  It is not an answer to your question, but related.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing are simply functions.

To take a related example from mathematics,

```
          /   x, if x >= 0
abs(x) =  |
          \  -x, otherwise
```

And you are just composing functions: `f(g(x))`.

You can somewhat make the correspondence to monads, but it is a bit of a stretch.  I think it is more that monads are extensions of functions rather than the other way around.

`flatMap` would be the composition operator: `o`  , ie `(f o g)(x) = f(g(x))`.  And `unit` would just be the identity operation: `I(x) = x`.

The three monad laws:

- Associativity: `f o (g o h) = (f o g) o h`
- Left unit: `I o f = f`
- Right unit: `f o I = f`

So instead of defining your `If` class, you can just stick to `def`, the usual function definition.  Functional programming!!!  In your case you can compose all your functions in any order since they always input/output `Foo` type.  You can compose functions in Scala with `val h = f _ compose h _`, or using `andThen`.